# How to run my colab notebook periodically

Tags: google-drive-api, scheduled-tasks, google-colaboratory

I've written a script in Google Colab that performs some queries via API to a server where I host some information, let's say weather data from several weather stations we own, that data is downloaded in a JSON format then I save those files in my Google Drive as I'll use them later in the same script to generate some condensed tables by country and by month, those summary files are also stored in my Google Drive account. After that, I send the summary files via email to some people.

I need to run this script every other day and, well, it is no big deal to do that, but I'd like to make it happen without human intervention, mainly because of scalability. One of the main points is that some libraries are not easy to install locally and it is way easier to make it work in Colab, that's why I don't use some solutions like crontab or windows scheduler to perform this, and I need to make the Colab notebook to run periodically.

I've tried solutions like PythonAnywhere, but I've spent too much time trying to modify the script to work with PyDrive and, so far, haven't achieved it. I've also tried to run it using GCP but haven't found how to access my Google Drive files yet using Google Cloud Functions. I've been also working on building an image using Docker and if I deploy it to someone else, it'll be working, but the idea is to make the running schedulable not only deployable. I've also read the Colabctl option but haven't been able to make it run yet.

Please, I'm open to receiving any suggestions in order to achieve my goal.

Thank you,

Billy.

Comment: Have you tried using the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api)?

Comment: Hi, @Aerials I've tried that but the issue is that it works, as I've read so far, with POST and GET using HTTP, and this script has to read/write over 300+ files each time since I store temporary files from each weather station. The other part is that I need to store the final files in another location, in a Google Drive from another user. Do you have kind of an example on how to do that? And, once again, how to make this script to run daily without human intervention? Thanks, Billy.

Comment: I am confused about your goal. You want to use Drive as a temporary storage or as a database? Drive API is a REST API, you can use client libraries, but to call the API requests are done using HTTP. Can you explain or simplify your explanation or your goal?

Comment: Hi @Aerials Thank you for your answer. The goal is to use Drive as storage. This is the thing, I'm using Drive to store the temporary data as well as the final data. I grant access to specific users to specific folders, then it's the best way, for me, to distribute the results. Is it possible to make it work this way using Google Cloud Functions? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

there is a paid scheduler https://cloud.google.com/scheduler

or you can use https://github.com/TensorTom/colabctl with your own cron

Comment: Hi, @flaxon I've tried scheduler but didn't find a way to make it works. Do you know how to make the Google Colab Notebook run using the Scheduler? And, as I mentioned, so far I haven't made the colabct to work.